# Load photos from JSON one by one

Tags: ios, xcode, json, image, gallery

I have a JSON service, where I use some photos. I want to make a thumbnail gallery from it:

```
    -(void)fillPhotos:(NSMutableArray *)json{
    _loadingLabel.alpha=0;
    [SV setScrollEnabled:YES];
    if(json.count>0){
        NSDictionary *json_dictionary=[json objectAtIndex:0]; 
        NSInteger i=0;
        for(i=0;i<[[json_dictionary objectForKey:@"Photos"] count];i++){
        NSDictionary *photosDic =[[json_dictionary objectForKey:@"Photos"] objectAtIndex:i] ;
        NSString *imageUrl = [photosDic objectForKey:@"URI"];
        UIImageView* photo;
        CGRect viewRect;
            if(i % 2){
            viewRect = CGRectMake(164,146*(i/2)+10*(i/2), 146, 146);
            NSLog(@"par");
            }else{
            viewRect = CGRectMake(10,146*(i/2)+10*(i/2), 146, 146);   
                NSLog(@"impar");
            }
            photo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
            photo.image=[UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: imageUrl]]];
            [SV addSubview:photo];
            SV.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,146*i+146);
            [SV reloadInputViews];
        }
    }
}
```

It works Okay, but I have two problems. First I want the view to load photo by photo, so the user don't have to wait for the end ond the cicle to view all the photos at once. Second I want the photo to crop in the center, but just occupy the 146x146 frame. But if I put the Top in contentmode the photo pulls out from his frame.

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, you need to load the images asynchronously. Exactly how to do this is a little beyond the scope of an answer (and partly up to you), but you probably want to look into either `NSURLConnection` or `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`.

For the second question, just set `photo.clipsToBounds = YES`.